# Magento 1.9 REST API Callback

Tags: magento-1.9, php, rest-api, oauth, phpstorm

so I just set up my M1.9 store, and want to set up a REST API. I wanted to test it out by retrieving a list of products. I only don't know what to put in the callbackurl field, online they say the location of the .php file I'm using but I'm running it locally and the magento server is on a dedicated server, so that doesn't work out.

Here's the code i use

```
<?php
$callbackUrl = "";
$temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl = "http://52.59.36.230/magento/oauth/initiate?oauth_callback=" . urlencode($callbackUrl);
$adminAuthorizationUrl = 'http://52.59.36.230/magento/admin/oauth_authorize';
$accessTokenRequestUrl = 'http://52.59.36.230/magento/oauth/token';
$apiUrl = 'http://52.59.36.230/magento/api/rest';
$consumerKey = '***';
$consumerSecret = '***';

session_start();
if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && isset($_SESSION['state']) && $_SESSION['state'] == 1) {
    $_SESSION['state'] = 0;
}
try {
    $authType = ($_SESSION['state'] == 2) ? OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_AUTHORIZATION : OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_URI;
    $oauthClient = new OAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1, $authType);
    $oauthClient->enableDebug();

    if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && !$_SESSION['state']) {
        $requestToken = $oauthClient->getRequestToken($temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl);
        $_SESSION['secret'] = $requestToken['oauth_token_secret'];
        $_SESSION['state'] = 1;
        header('Location: ' . $adminAuthorizationUrl . '?oauth_token=' . $requestToken['oauth_token']);
        exit;
    } else if ($_SESSION['state'] == 1) {
        $oauthClient->setToken($_GET['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['secret']);
        $accessToken = $oauthClient->getAccessToken($accessTokenRequestUrl);
        $_SESSION['state'] = 2;
        $_SESSION['token'] = $accessToken['oauth_token'];
        $_SESSION['secret'] = $accessToken['oauth_token_secret'];
        header('Location: ' . $callbackUrl);
        exit;
    } else {
        $oauthClient->setToken($_SESSION['token'], $_SESSION['secret']);
        $resourceUrl = "$apiUrl/products";
        $oauthClient->fetch($resourceUrl);
        $productsList = json_decode($oauthClient->getLastResponse());
        print_r($productsList);
    }
} catch (OAuthException $ex ) {
    print_r($e);
}
?>
```

Anyone who could help me further ?

EDIT:

I'm running my code trough PHPStorm, so it uses my localhost. The magento server is running on an AWS instance.

Comment: After authorization the call back url will be redirected to the place we want e.g.http://magento.loc/api/rest/products  or function we want to call e.g. http://magento.loc/restconnect/test/callback. I used this link for my ref. http://inchoo.net/magento/consuming-magento-rest-zend_oauth_consumer/.

Comment: @Arjun ok so when I put in the magentoloc/api/rest/products it gives me an access denied ?

Comment: Yes for guest customer the api/rest/products are denied. You need to pass authorization key along with it in header for allowing it access as a customer.

Comment: @Arjun I'm confused, the WEB API roles are set up and I use the 2 given keys in my script, what else is missing ?

Comment: I would suggest you to check these page http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/testing_rest_resources.html.

Comment: @Arjun I'll take a look at it!

Comment: @Arjun I don't see what's wrong here, I get to the point in the web page where I can authorize the user or reject him, when I authorize I get an access denied, but I allowed access to everything?

Answer (score 0):

This $callbackURL should work in the sample above.

```
$callbackUrl = 'http' . (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 's' : '') . '://' . "{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}/{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}";
```